# Search through Google form data

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I have a Google Form that outputs data like this:

*Buyers* sheet's row example (for each buyer who filled the form):

`Timestamp | User 1 | Product 1 | Price 1 | Product 2 | Price 2 | Product 3 | Price 3 ...`

`Timestamp | User 2 | Product 1 | Price 1 | Product 2 | Price 2 | Product 3 | Price 3 ...`

And on another sheet called *Bids*:

`Product 1 | Base Price`

`Product 2 | Base Price`

`Product 3 | Base Price`

The result I'd like to achieve is getting all the bids for the different products and display next to each product the highest bid with the corresponding username. I've tried with `lookupv` and `query` but did not succeed, I'm not exactly an expert in Google Sheets (that's an euphemism).

Any ideas?

Here is an copy of the actual sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bW_MlogHpXQk-_DZupE22No7KwUyZesqggsEdQaXPgw/edit?usp=sharing

With an example on the Bids sheet for computer of what I'm trying to get.
Buyers is a sheet populated automatically from a Google form.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: There you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bW_MlogHpXQk-_DZupE22No7KwUyZesqggsEdQaXPgw/edit?usp=sharing

With an example on the Bids sheet for computer of what I'm trying to get.
Buyers is a sheet populated automatically from a Google form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, SORT(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(
 FILTER(Buyers!C2:1000, MOD(COLUMN(Buyers!C1:1)-1, 2)=0)<>"", 
 FILTER(Buyers!C2:1000, MOD(COLUMN(Buyers!C1:1)-1, 2)=0)&"×"&
 FILTER(Buyers!C2:1000, MOD(COLUMN(Buyers!C1:1), 2)=0)&"×"&Buyers!B2:B1000, )), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), "×"), 2, 0), {2, 3}, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks a lot! I'll dig into it to understand how that works.